# apple ios app icon issue

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I want to know is there any way i can show the app icon with a transparent background, for example a white circle and the area around it as transparent, thought the image har transparent canvas. But app shows black background of the circle icon.

All relies are welcomed.

Comment: I'm afraid iOS app icons do not have transparent backgrounds. If you did do so, the background will be composited against the black color. You won't be seeing through the wall paper on the device in the icon.

Comment: This is not possible, all app icons have a black background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app icon will be displayed as the same sized round-cornered square button as all the other apps -- there's no way to truly make it look like a round button, for example.

If you control the device(s) on which the app will be installed, then you can add a background to your icon that matches the wallpaper on the device. Don't forget to turn off the shine effect by setting the UIPrerenderedIcon flag in your Info.plist to YES.

Comment: ok thanks, i was thinking to make similar icons for both ios and android.